# Keyclock console UI requiredUserActions field not auto populating on password expired if we are using Java SDK

Tags: java, sdk, keycloak

I am working on a spring boot project there we are using the Keycloak SDK for user registration and pin validation. now, we are facing a challenge if the user's password expires, and need to alert the mobile users in advance.

Query:

1. How to get the pin expiry date from Keycloak using the Java SDK?
2. Why Keycloak UI not auto-populating the requiredUserActions field on password expired if we are using a Java SDK[image]? Is there any configuration that needs to be done in keycloak UI